# Is there a way to control the SilhouetteFX 5.2 GUI via python scripting?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to make a script that focuses the timeline window to the current keyframe (as on very large plates of up to 2000 frames or more, rotoscoping can be extra tedious when you have to scroll the timeline whenever you want to delete the current keyframe).

I am looking at the official scripting reference and can't find any way to do this.